# DotNetCoreCLI@2 pack task ignores version suffix directive

Tags: build, azure-devops

I'm creating my first Azure build pipeline for a .Net Core 2.1 solution. I've had success with `DotNetCoreCLI@2` for all of my steps, that is, except for the pack step.

This works, and is currently what I have resorted to:

```
- script: |
    dotnet pack src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj --version-suffix $(VersionSuffix) --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore --no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: 'dotnet pack [$(BuildConfiguration)]'
```

This does not work, in that it ignores the `--version-suffix` directive:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2   
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    # packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj; **/!*Test*.csproj' - TODO pack all projects, except test projects
    packagesToPack: 'src/MyProject/MyProject.csproj'
    arguments: '--version-suffix $(VersionSuffix) --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore --no-build --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'dotnet pack [$(BuildConfiguration)]'
```

(I've left one of my TODOs in there as a side quest)

Also, the version prefix resides in the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

    <PackageId>MyProject</PackageId>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>A description</Description>
    <VersionPrefix>0.1.0</VersionPrefix>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
<Project/>
```

When I use the `dotnet pack` I see a NuGet package with the full version (i.e. `<prefix>-<suffix>`) as I expect; e.g. `0.1.0-190813.02.abcdef`.

When I use the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task the version is limited to the version prefix; e.g. `0.1.0`.

What have I missed? Ideally I would like the pipeline yaml file to be consistent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What have I missed? Ideally I would like the pipeline yaml file to be consistent.

No, you did not miss anything. This behavior is by designed for `DotNetCoreCLI@2`.

When you check that task in the classic editor without YAML, you can see there is no such **Arguments** option, instead of **Pack options**:

[image]

So, we could use this option to define the package version.

**Besides**, according to the document [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments), the description for the arguments when you use it in YAML:

[image]

**The argument `-version` for `Pack` is not accept**, we need use the custom command, which is the method you are using now.

So, you are on the right way now, do not need to worry about it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a little subtle. Admittedly, I hadn't noticed the fine print. Thank-you, I'll leave my solution as is. Thanks.

Comment: Why is `pack` the odd one out?

Comment: @JevonKendon, Sorry, I don't know the reason for it. This should be the implementation limitation of the underlying method. Maybe we need to ask the developer of this task. You can try to get the reason from here:https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues

Answer (score 6):

I also stumbled onto this problem and found out that DotNetCoreCLI is not going to help me with version suffixes per @Leo answer.

Way to overcome this problem is to pack your project with `powershell` task. A simple example:

````
      - powershell: 'dotnet pack -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) --no-build --no-restore -c ${{ parameters.configuration }} ${{ parameters.projectPath }}'
    ```
````

Comment: This is the correct answer. `DotNetCoreCLI` simply refuses to acknowledge any existence of VersionSuffix even if using custom command.

Answer (score -1):

The way I fixed was to use Nuget Command

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Pack Test'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/test.nuspec'
    versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'
```